# Calculate viewport dimensions and pixel ratio of latest devices for Chrome Devtools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools, screen

I am wondering if their is some way to get the viewport dimensions and pixel ratio for the latest AND upcoming devices so that I can add those devices into Chrome Devtools for emulation.

As developers, I believe it is very important for us to make sure our apps and websites look good on devices which are yet to be released in the market.

**For example, how do I calculate the above details for S20 Ultra (newest device in market at time of writing this question), given that I know the screen size in inches (H (6.29 in), W (2.83 in)), device PPI (511), device screen resolution (3200 × 1440 px) and aspect ratio (20:9)?**

TIA.